# Outer query count is wrong

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(X.ACTIVITY_ID) 
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         ACTIVITY_ID 
     FROM 
         mi_s_data.dbo.[MI_FACT_ACTIVITY] 
     WHERE  
         Date_Key BETWEEN (convert(int, convert(varchar(10), DatePart(yyyy,GetDate()), 112)) - 2)*10000 + 101 
                      AND convert(int, convert(varchar(10), GetDate(), 112))
     UNION
     SELECT  
         ACTIVITY_ID  
     FROM 
         [MI_S_DATA].[DBO].[MOS_FACT_ACTIVITY_V1] MFA
     WHERE 
         Date_Key BETWEEN (convert(int, convert(varchar(10), DatePart(yyyy,GetDate()), 112)) - 2)*10000 + 101 
                      AND convert(int, convert(varchar(10), GetDate(), 112))
      AND MFA.ACTIVITY_UID IS NULL) X  --Count is 1763046
```

While running individual count like below:

```
select count(*) 
from 
    (SELECT ACTIVITY_ID 
     FROM mi_s_data.dbo.[MI_FACT_ACTIVITY] 
     WHERE Date_Key BETWEEN (convert(int, convert(varchar(10), DatePart(yyyy,GetDate()), 112)) - 2)*10000 + 101 
                        AND convert(int, convert(varchar(10), GetDate(), 112))) a   --5774079

 select count(*) 
 from 
     (SELECT ACTIVITY_ID  
      FROM [MI_S_DATA].[DBO].[MOS_FACT_ACTIVITY_V1] MFA
      WHERE Date_Key BETWEEN (convert(int, convert(varchar(10), DatePart(yyyy,GetDate()), 112)) - 2)*10000 + 101 AND convert(int, convert(varchar(10), GetDate(), 112)) 
        AND MFA.ACTIVITY_UID IS NULL) a--0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Kindly provide some sample data from each `select`

Comment: You are using `UNION` . `UNION` will elimiate any duplicates `ACTIVITY_ID` . `UNION ALL` does not

Comment: Agree with @Squirrel; essentially by using `union` your top level count is really a `count(distinct activity_id)` as opposed to `count(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(X.ACTIVITY_ID) 
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         ACTIVITY_ID 
     FROM 
         mi_s_data.dbo.[MI_FACT_ACTIVITY] 
     WHERE  
         Date_Key BETWEEN (convert(int, convert(varchar(10), DatePart(yyyy,GetDate()), 112)) - 2)*10000 + 101 
                      AND convert(int, convert(varchar(10), GetDate(), 112))
     UNION ALL
     SELECT  
         ACTIVITY_ID  
     FROM 
         [MI_S_DATA].[DBO].[MOS_FACT_ACTIVITY_V1] MFA
     WHERE 
         Date_Key BETWEEN (convert(int, convert(varchar(10), DatePart(yyyy,GetDate()), 112)) - 2)*10000 + 101 
                      AND convert(int, convert(varchar(10), GetDate(), 112))
      AND MFA.ACTIVITY_UID IS NULL) X  --Count is 1763046
```